# What is the lifespan of the reference variable to a "new" object in php?

Tags: php

Say I have a php file called a.php:

```
//a.php
<?php require_once('b.php'); ?>
```

In b.php I have:

```
//b.php
<?php
     if (!$obj) $obj = new myclass();
?>
```

Then what's the lifespan of `$obj`?
If I refresh a.php several times, will I get multiple instances of `myclass`?

Also if I want to use `$obj` reference in other pages, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object lives at MOST until the script ends, and in general objects do NOT persist between page loads. You can reference $obj from other *scripts* which are included from a.php, but only if they are included on *the same request*... Other requests may also include b.php, but it will indeed be a *new* instance of myclass.

In order to refer to the same entity (i.e. the same conceptual object), you need a persistence mechanism, and a way to initialize any given instance of myclass with the persisted data (which is then usually passed via URL parameters).